# Set value as zero if value is not present - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The table has the following fields
length, breadth, height, width, depth

I need to set value as zero to these fields if value is not present.

i have written the following

```
before_save :fill_empty_values

def fill_empty_values
    self.length ||= 0
    self.breadth ||= 0
    self.height ||= 0
    self.width ||= 0
    self.depth ||= 0
end
```

Is this the correct approach to set default values to the fields?
**Any idea on how to optimize the code? something like looping the fields and setting the value?**

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a migration to add default columns to all the columns. Assuming your table is called 'dimensions', and the values are integers:

```
[:length, :breadth, :height, :width, :depth].each do |attribute|
  change_column :dimensions, attribute, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `default to 0` in a migration

```
add_column :table_name, :length, :integer, null: false, default: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping variant would be...

```
FIELDS = %w(length breadth height width depth)

def fill_empty_fields
  FIELDS.each do {|field| send(field + '=', send(field).presence || 0)}
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I blame age and my eyesight.